# jQuery stops working after multiple calls to the load() method

Tags: jquery

I am designing a website and I'm using jQuery. One a certain page, I use the load() method when the user clicks on a list item in order to load the appropriate content to a section of the page. This is working the first few times that I click on the link but then all of a sudden query stops working. When I restart eclipse everything works fine for the first few clicks but the same thing happens again. for example, I have the following code:

```
$('#someListElement').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#targetSection').load('theJavaServlet', function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

When I click on the list item with the id 'someListElement' I get the message. This works the first three or four times, but suddenly it no longer works and all jQuery functionality on the page stops working.Lets say I click the list item three times without it working. When I close eclipse I get three 'test' messages. When I re-open eclipse the cycle starts again. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: add parameters to the callback function like `$( "#targetSection" ).load( "theJavaServlet", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});` to see what error you get

Comment: I am getting the following error: "0 error"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. While debugging I replaced the javaServlet in the load method with an html page and the problem disappeared, so I realised that the problem must be with the servlet. When I checked I noticed that the servlet, which uses a connection pool to establish a connection with a database, is not freeing the connection. The pool.freeConnection(connection) method was commented out. so multiple calls to the servlet was using up all the connections. Once I removed the comments and allowed the servlet to free the connection everything worked fine.